How to correlate two variables together with lag
I am curious to know about measures of correlation for the frequency of an event against a continuous variable (I am aware this question is similar to this one).
In this case, I've plotted my weight on a given day (in kilograms, real-valued) against the frequency of eating a particular kind of food, summed on a daily basis. In both cases the moving average is used in the plots, with k=15 (i.e. 15 day window) and using copy-on padding. copy-on is when the edge value at both ends is repeated to handle the edges of the input, as opposed to zero-padding or valid-padding. The bottom-right plot is a sum of the types of food aggregated together.
Notwithstanding the issues in this approach (bias with copy-on padding, smoothing leaks data from the future into the current value), I am curious to know how I can correlate weight with the different variables to see what makes a bigger difference and what doesn't. I'm not committed to this methodology, I just thought it would plot well.
I've tried using the Pearson correlation coefficient to answer this question, and am confused why some plots have a p-value of 0. This seems odd to me. I also don't know how to account for the lag, in particular.
Any advice on this or resources/concepts to look at much appreciated - and happy to disclose any data or code as needed!

